# Await on an async function called with call or apply with Babel

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, ecmascript-next

How do I `await` on `async` function called with `call` or `apply` with `Babel`?

Below is an example, where `getOrders` is an `async` method of a `Service` class:

```
class Service() {
   async getOrders(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
      return await this.anotherService.getOrders(arg1, arg2, arg3);
   }
}

let service = new Service();
// ...
// Babel doesn't compile 
// let stream = await service.getOrders.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
// producing SyntaxError: Unexpected token for await
let stream = service.getOrders.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
stream.pipe(res); // obviously not working without await in the prev line
```

Comment: Are you asking what to do when you want to call an async function outside of another async function? It's not clear what this has to do with call/apply/bind, or what `this` you are passing to `call` in your question.

Comment: @loganfsmyth no, I'm asking how to `await` on an `async` function called with `call` or `apply`.

Comment: You'd use await just like you normally do. Updated my answer.

Comment: @loganfsmyth `call` is not an `async` function (although in this case it calls an `async` function), so `await` here doesn't work.  at least currently with `babel`.

Comment: `await` just takes a promise. e.g. `var streamPromise = service.getOrders(); var stream = await streamPromise;`. The fact that you are using call just changes how you call `getOrders`, it does not affect how `await` works. If you have a specific example that is not working, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `async function` returns a Promise, and `await` accepts a promise. There is no requirement that all `async` functions be called via await. If you want to use an async function inside a standard JS function, you would directly use the result promise. In your case, calling a function with `.call` will still return a promise like any other function, so you'd they pass that promise to await:

```
async function doThing(){
  let service = new Service();

  var stream = await service.getOrders.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3)
  stream.pipe(res);
}
```

Comment: This is what I would expect, but `babel` doesn't seem to support it currently.

Comment: Please provide an example that demonstrates this in Babel, since it definitely should work there too. Your current example doesn't even use await.

Comment: Because `babel` doesn't compile `let stream = await service.getOrders.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);`.  Gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` for `await`.

Comment: You'd have to put that `await` inside of an async function too. That's why I asked "Are you asking what to do when you want to call an async function outside of another async function?" above, and you said no.

Comment: `getOrders` is `async` and does have `await`

Comment: In order to have `await something;` anywhere in your function, that function must also be an async function. In your case, your `let service = new Service();` and such, are not inside an async function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80797/discussion-between-loganfsmyth-and-kyrylkov).

Answer (score 0):

[From the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30894302/9):

> The problem was that `let stream = service.getOrders.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);` was in an anonymous function inside a regular function. Instead of marking anonymous function `async`, I did it for a regular function causing Babel `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.
>
> Thanks to [@loganfsmyth for leading me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30895391/211627) to the solution.

Answer (score -4):

You can try a wrapper like this:

```
class Service() {
   async getOrders(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
   // ....
   };
   wrappedOrders(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
       let res = await getOrders(arg1, arg2, arg3);
       return res;
   }
}
```

and call the wrappedOrders this way:

```
let stream = service.wrappedOrders.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Comment: Every function with `await` is `async`, so `wrappedOrders` must by `async` also, which takes us back to my question